# fade out div before another fades in — Jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I'm very new at this jquery business — if you can find it in your hearts to forgive me and my ignorant questions, I'd be very grateful.

My dilemma: I have two divs, and I need one to fade out *before* another fades in.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#about").click(function () {
            $("#aboutinfo").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#contact").click(function () {
            $("#contactinfo").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The website in question is [this](http://tomjhume.com/camelot).

Also, I take it I have written that jquery wrong, because both statements have their own  `<script></script>` tags?

Thanks to whoever can help :)

edit: this seems to not be working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#music").click(function () {
            $("#musicinfo").fadeToggle();
            $("#about").click(function () {
            $("#aboutinfo").fadeToggle();
            $("#contact").click(function () {
            $("#contactinfo").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you want to do ? Fade both divs after click on one div ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animations all accept callback functions that will be called as one animation finishes:

```
$('#about').click(function() {
    $('#contactinfo, #musicinfo').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#aboutinfo').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

If there is nothing to fade, (i.e. no visible elements), the callback will fire immediately.

... and yes, this could all be within one `<script>` block, and within one `$(document).ready` listener:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#about').click(function() { ... });
   $('#contact').click(function() { ... });
});
```

If you used classes as well as IDs, you would probably be able to write a single click handler for all elements. Something like:

```
$('.header-item').click(function() {
   var target = $('#' + this.id + 'info');
   $('.info-item').not(target).fadeOut(function() {
      target.fadeIn();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've hit a dead end at the first hurdle though. I've tried to put it all between two script tags but it's stopped working. `$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#music").click(function () {
            $("#musicinfo").fadeToggle();
            $("#about").click(function () {
            $("#aboutinfo").fadeToggle();
            $("#contact").click(function () {
            $("#contactinfo").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
`

Comment: @TomJulianHume: you're missing two sets of `});`. There should be one after each `fadeToggle();` Right now, you're binding the click listener to `about` *within* the click listener to `music`, and none of your code will execute because of mismatched brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function()
{
$("#div1").hide();
$("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

It will fade out quickly and will fade in another div.